# How to set pinmode for an analog pin dynamically

Tags: arduino, atmega

I am building a test code for atmega328p using arduino ide. 
We can set digital pin using simple int variable;

how can i achieve this with analog pin?

I tried looking into the core code base of arduino.h but didn't find anything defined there for analog pins so i am not sure How to handle this.
I have work around for this but I don't want to try that without understanding this.

```
//this we can do for digital pins

int pin = 0;

void someMethod(){
   pinMode(pin,INPUT);
}
```

Comment: I posted an answer below.  Please click the check mark to accept it, or let me know what's wrong.

Comment: Please read the ATmega328P datasheet, particularly on how to use ADC (analog-to-digital conversion).

Answer (score 0):

The values of things like `A0` and `A1` are small, positive numbers, so you can store them in an `int` variable if you want.  Using a `uint8_t` would make more sense though.

You can see how those names are defined for the Arduino Uno (ATmega328P) here:

https://github.com/arduino/ArduinoCore-avr/blob/master/variants/standard/pins_arduino.h

```cpp
#define PIN_A0   (14)
#define PIN_A1   (15)
#define PIN_A2   (16)
#define PIN_A3   (17)
#define PIN_A4   (18)
#define PIN_A5   (19)
#define PIN_A6   (20)
#define PIN_A7   (21)

static const uint8_t A0 = PIN_A0;
static const uint8_t A1 = PIN_A1;
static const uint8_t A2 = PIN_A2;
static const uint8_t A3 = PIN_A3;
static const uint8_t A4 = PIN_A4;
static const uint8_t A5 = PIN_A5;
static const uint8_t A6 = PIN_A6;
static const uint8_t A7 = PIN_A7;
```